# Does anyone know the specific reasons why Google do not recommend using a magnet as input for Cardboard?

Tags: android, google-cardboard, virtual-reality

I've been trying to set up a "VR Box" VR headset with Google Cardboard. That headset does not have an input button, but I've made a QR code for a VR profile that accepts a magnetic button input. It kind of works - if you wave a magnet near the top left of the phone (a Samsung S5 Mini) as it sits in the viewer, it mostly triggers a click event. But not reliably.

Google clearly know that magnet input is not reliable and discourage it in the Cardboard help: https://support.google.com/cardboard/manufacturers/answer/6323710

My question is: does anyone know the metrics Google have used to decide that magnetic input is not reliable?

Answer (score 0):

Magnets in Cardboard are a very neat idea, but one that cannot properly work on many devices.

The main reason is that phone manufacturers are more and more cheap these days. Gyroscopes are quite rare in todays phones, mostly flagship devices have them. Some major software has also disabled the use of gyroscopes in recent updates, for example Google Chrome Android stopped using it for an orientation sensor.

It might be a surprise, because VR views work on the budget devices, but it's true - what you're seeing is something called sensor fusion - it uses an accelerometer and magnetometer to simulate a gyroscope. This works fairly well, but with way less precision and some artifacts (try moving the phone in VR mode fast vertically without rotating it - the view will rotate).

And guess what happens if you put a big magnet near the magnetometer - it barely works at all.

TL;DR: adding a magnetic button makes the head tracking even worse.

---

What you should do is make your own input touch button. I have upgraded a few cardboards this way. You have to press the screen somehow.

The best way is to get some anti-electrostatic foil and make a button of it, so when pressed it will touch the screen and your finger at the same time. You could also use a very short and narrow copper cable from the screen to the outside and press it with your finger.
A simple hole for inserting your finger works too.